# how to set different banner for multiple website in magento

Tags: magento

I'm using [Magestore Banner Slider](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/banner-slider.html) for rotating banner in the homepage. I set up two different websites using this [link](http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/how-to-set-multiple-websites-with-multiple-store-views-in-magento/)

But now I want to set up two different banner for the two different website. So how do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are press the button Manage Banners or something similar that shows you the grid with all the banner that you have you will notice on the left side just above the title Banner Manager a dropdown list.
choose the different store view and create the banners for each store.
Cheers

Comment: Ok, but how I add banner id in the same 'Home Page'?

Comment: The home page is a CMS page.Make different home pages for different store views.